# Why am I unable to get the correct row fields for this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 select  CountryCode,Language, floor(max(percentage)) as speakers 
  from countrylanguage 
  group by CountryCode;
```

As intuitive I want Language that corresponds to max percentage in the table countrylanguage. However this doesn't seem to work. What should I change here to make it work?
More information for you:

```
desc countrylanguage;
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CountryCode | char(3)       | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| Language    | char(30)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| IsOfficial  | enum('T','F') | NO   |     | F       |       |
| Percentage  | float(4,1)    | NO   |     | 0.0     |       |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  select  CountryCode, Language, floor(percentage) as speakers 
    from countrylanguage c
    where percentage = (select max(percentage) from countrylanguage c2 where c2.countrycode = c.countrycode group by c2.countrycode)
```

Comment: That's worse than my answer. You are getting me multiple rows!

Comment: you want max percentage per country?

Comment: Yes Akshet. I  want max percentage per country alongwith correct language.